# How to have an unified color handling to be used on VCL and FMX?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl, delphi-xe6

I know this should be simple, but I am not getting.

I have a software that have a shared source code between FMX an VCL.

There are some places now that I need to reference colors. And this reference needs to automatically translated to the proper platform. This shared code is stored in a package that is not scoped.

I am getting part of the idea from the Platform services to implement the platform side part.

But I dont know what to use that can be the same for both platforms. Should i create may own TColor? and each platform specific implementation translate from that to the platform one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors work differently in VCL and FMX, so you are likely going to have to implement some kind of custom abstraction layer between them for your shared code to use.

Comment: But can I go for TAlphaColor only constants? I was just looking that the TAlphaColor constants are available for VCL also. Sure that handling it is different, but I need to save the value, assign thru many classes, etc, before getting used. So can I do that?